# Integrals convergence and divergence

Tags: definite-integrals

let $f$ be a fucntion defined on $R^+$, let S= $\int_a^\infty f(x)$ with $a\ge0$. I need to know if there exists a theorem that states that if : $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x) \rightarrow c$ where $c\neq 0$ hence the integral diverges? and if not, is there a theorem that can prove $\int_a^\infty f(x)$ divergence through the limit of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) \to c$
where $c > 0$,
there is a $d$
such that
$f(x) > c/2$
for $x > d$.

Then
$\int_d^M f(x) dx
> (M-d)(c/2)
\to \infty$
as $M \to \infty$.

A similar argument holds
if $c < 0$.

Comment: can i know how did you arrive to the 2nd inequality i.e $\int_d^M f(x) dx
\ge (M-d)(c/2) $
 please

Comment: f(x) > c/2 for x > d, and the length of the interval is M-d.